# Numbers divisible by their constituents

Tags: php, arrays

i need to print numbers from 0 to n, that divides by all of their constituents.
i wrote code, but it prints numbers which divides at least on the one constituent too:

```
$n = $_POST['inp'];
$numbers = range(0, $n);

foreach ($numbers as $value) {
    $value = (string)$value;
    if ( strpos($value,"0") !== false ) { continue; }
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($value);$i++) {
        if (($value % $value[$i]) == 0) { 
            echo  $value , "\n";        
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about breaking out of the loop when the remainder is *not* 0. If the remainder is 0 on the last pass through the loop (`$i == strlen($value)-1`), then you will know that the remainder was 0 for every constituent digit. In code:

```
if (($value % $value[$i]) != 0) {
    break;
} else if ($i == strlen($value)-1) {
    echo  $value , "\n";
}
```

There are other ways to approach this, but this is the closest to your existing code.